# assign role after registration (male female)

Tags: 7, users

I need users to check male/female option when creating an account. Then I need to automatically assign a role male/female to the users. 
How can this be achieved? Is there any module which I can use?

Comment: Are you asking which code you should use, or if there is a module you could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a **field** to the user entity at *admin/config/people/accounts/fields*. Let's use the *List (text)* type and call it "field_gender" with the possible values of *female|Female* and *male|Male*. Display it on the user registration form.

Then you can use **[Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)** to react e.g. when someone creates an account and perform various actions. The idea is that you create two different rules for assigning either the male or the female role.

- Install Rules if you haven't already done so, and create a new
  rule at *admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add*.  Choose a name
  for it and tag it if you want. The rule should react on the following
  event: ***After saving a new user account***.
- Add a condition in the next step and choose *Data
  comparison*. Then type or select *account:field-gender* in the data
  selector.
- Choose the data value in the next step to be *Female*.
- Now your condition is ready, add an action, select *Add user role*,
  then choose the female role.
- Repeat these steps and create a rule
  for assigning the male role.

Comment: great, looks like simple solution.